# How to swipe image + text in android

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

Hi experts, can you please suggest me how can i start the work to get only that image+text swipping effect. Actually, we have an RSS link, from that link we need to fetch and display the images and description as shown above. I have completed RSS data fetching and image displaying with respect to left/right arrows but i could not able to add swiping effect on images. In many examples, onTouchEvent() method is used but it applies to entire layout swipping, i dont want that effect.

Thanks

venu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way to do it would be to replace your ImageView with a [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html). It is a simple widget for displaying a rotating strip of images. You can then implement one of the callbacks (onFling would work) to know when to load new data for the list view below.

Here's the official Android [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html) on using the Gallery widget.

Cheers

Comment: thnaks for your reply. I have seen that gallery example, only images are loaded into gallery but my requirement is to load image+text into gallery. Can you please suggest me in that way?

Comment: Sure: first check out this example: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/Gallery1.html

Notice the ImageAdapter class that extends BaseAdapter. It contains a getView method. You can create a custom View containing the image+text and return it from that method. This view can be specified using XML, like all your other views.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have done the same thing as you suggest..it is much similar to working with custom list view.

Answer (score 2):

Venu,

Create a custom view that contains and ImageView and a TextView

You can set up a gesture listener on any view.
The code looks something like this:

```
protected static final float LARGE_MOVE = 60;
private SimpleOnGestureListener gestureListener;
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

gestureListener = new SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onFling(android.view.MotionEvent e1,
                    android.view.MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                    float velocityY) {

                int _index = //your current image
                int _size = //number of images you have to swipe through

                if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > LARGE_MOVE) {
                    // Log.d("swipe", "SWIPE LEFT");
                    _index += 1;
                    if (_index > _size - 1) {
                        _index = 0;
                    }

                    return true;
                } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > LARGE_MOVE) {
                    // Log.d("swipe", "SWIPE RIGHT");
                    _index -= 1;
                    if (_index < 0) {
                        _index = _size - 1;
                    }
                    return true;

                }
                return false;
            };
        };
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, gestureListener);
```

Then you need to relay touch events to your gesture detector.

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

The swipe gesture will let you keep track of which position of your data you're in.
Then its a simple matter of updating the text and the imageView or if you need to animate, you simply animate between two or more instances of your custom view.

Hope that helps. Good luck

Comment: thanks for your reply. the onTouchEvent() method will be notified if we swipe anywhere on the total screen but i dont want that. We have to keep the swipe effect only on that imageView. Is it possible to set swiping effect only on ImageView?

Comment: you can just add the listener to the Image View you need. for example ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_home);
  iv.setOnTouchListener(//onTouchListener or your activity implementing onTouchListener interface);

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `ViewPager`.

This would be a great link to start with. 
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

You don't have to manage the touch event. You just have to add the views that are to be swiped.

Comment: Agreed. ViewPager is best way to create a slider with today's Android, optimized in a lot of ways too.